# If $f(t)$ is periodic, is there any $t$ that would equal to DC components?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, periodic-functions

Suppose $f(t)$ is periodic with period $T$. Would there be $t$ that would necessarily equal to DC component (it can be scaled)? By DC component, I mean $F(0)$ where $F$ is fourier coefficient of $f$.

Comment: Is there $t$ such that $f(t) \equiv F(0)$? I do not think so. However, if what you mean is that there exists some $t\in[0,T]$ for which $f(t) = F(0)$, then probably so for continuous functions. You could probably prove that with the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given a continuous function f(t) that is periodic with period T,
and the Fourier transform of that function F(w),
then there will necessarily always be some time t where F(0) == f(t).
(That time t will be different for different functions f(t).)
F(0) is also called the DC component, also called the average value of f(t).
This can be proven using the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/intermediate_value_theorem), as [AnonSubmitter85](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33383/anonsubmitter85) pointed out.

The only way for a periodic function to *not* have such a point is for the periodic function to not be continuous.
One simple example is a rectangle wave where

- g(t) = 1 for 0 <= t < T/3, and
- g(t) = 0 for T/3 <= t < T, and
- g(t) is periodic with period T.

The average value of such a square wave, G(0), is 1/3.
But the function g(t) never exactly equals 1/3 -- it's value is always either 0 or 1 at all times, with discontinuities where it jumps from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0.